# On Select radio button value show in div and hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I use 6 radio button for six different value, I want to select one button from in these and the value of select button show in upper div 
Here I use a java script for show and hide radio button

```
<script> $(document).ready(function(){  
   $("#cityshow").click(function(){    
      $("#citybox").toggle();  
   });
});
</script>
```

Here is My [JSfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sac050/fuNd7/)

Comment: Question seems unclear, rephrasing needed..

Comment: What do you want?????????????????????????

Comment: why this question is upvoted?

Comment: @LOL May be due to the OP's profile pic.

Comment: pls check my js fiddle 
here when i select one value first Neem Ka thana then the value of this button show on top where written "sikar" and hide citycollection box

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I am also thinking to change my profile pic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cityshow").click(function(){
      $("#citybox").toggle();
    });

    $('#citybox input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var buttonValue = $(this).val();
        $("#citybox").toggle();
        $('#cityshow').text(buttonValue);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuNd7/7/)

UPDATE:

To insert the same value into the element

`<input id="cityid" type="hidden" name="" value="" >`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cityshow").click(function(){
      $("#citybox").toggle();
    });

    $('#citybox input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var buttonValue = $(this).val();
        $("#citybox").toggle();
        $('#cityshow').text(buttonValue);
        $('#cityid').val(buttonValue); // inserts value into input
    });
});
```

Please note, if you intend to use the value of the hidden input in a post request, then you should use the name attribute:

`<input id="cityid" type="hidden" name="cityid" value="" >`

Comment: but citycollection class not hide after select value

Comment: No problem. If it's the correct answer, then please tick it, thanks!

Comment: sir can i also insert that value in  this value option <input id="cityid" type="hidden" name="" value="" >

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cityshow").click(function(){
        $("#citybox").toggle();
    });
    $("#citybox input:radio").click(function() {
        $("#citybox").toggle();
        $("#cityshow").text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is another handler `click()` on radio buttons and if they are checked you have to set it in the upper div like following

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click',function(){
     if(this.checked){
        // $(this).closest(".citycollection").siblings(".citybox").text(this.value); // Set value to citybox
         $("#cityshow").text(this.value);
         $("#citybox").hide(); // hide city box
     } 
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fuNd7/6/)